# Prove $ a_ {n} $ converges to 0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be a real-valued bounded sequence.
Assume $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(a_{2 n}-2 a_{n}\right)=0$
Assume $w$ is an accumulation point of the sequence $a_{n}$.
I previously proved that $2^{k} w$ is also an accumulation point of $ a_n$

Now, I am asked to prove that $ a _ { n } $ converges to 0. So far, I have proved by contradiction that $w= 0$. But I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Do you know compactness?

Comment: I haven't studied that yet, no

Comment: You have essentially proved that any accumulation point of $(a_n)$ is 0. I claim that since your sequence is bounded this is sufficient. Try by contradiction.

Comment: And how do I know there is no more accumulation points other than the ones of $2^{k}w$?

Comment: If $|a_n|\le M$ for every $n$ then every accumulation point has absolute value no larger than  $M$. So $2^k|w|\le M$ for $k=1,2,\dots$, hence 4w=0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, that is what I did to prove w=0. But how does that prove the  sequence itself converges?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple fact about bounded sequences as was stated in the comments: a bounded sequence converges iff it has only one accumulutation point. Here is a proof that doesn't use this fact.

Assume that your sequence doesn't converge to $0$. Then there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ s.t. for all $N \in \mathbb N$ there exists $n \ge N$ s.t. $|x_n| \ge \varepsilon$. Thus, there exists a subsequence $x_{n_1}, x_{n_2}, \dots$ s.t. $|x_{n_k}| \ge \varepsilon$ for all $k$. Now using iterations of the fact $\lim (x_{2n_k} - 2x_{n_k}) = 0$ we obtain $\lim (x_{2^m n_k} - 2^mx_{n_k}) = 0$. Using the estimation $|x_{n_k}| \ge \varepsilon$ we deduce that for all $A > 0$ there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $|x_{n}| \ge A$. Indeed, take $m \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $\varepsilon 2^m > A$ and use the foregoing limit. Thus, your sequence is not bounded.

Comment: @Erik Dz In addition to this, notice that you have all the ingredients to prove the astonishing theorem : any sequence $(a_n)$ converges to a real number $a$ if and only if for all subsequence $(a_{\sigma(n)})$ you can extract a subsubsequence $(a_{\sigma \circ \phi(n)})$ with limit $a$.